# Unknown provider: ifFilterProvider <- ifFilter no angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, app, controller, angular-providers

Tenho seguinte em meu app.js

```
(function(){    
  'use strict';    
  angular
 .module('app', ['ngResource','ngRoute'])
 .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
 })
 .controller('AppCtrl', ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$location", "$timeout",
    function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    }]);    
}());
```

Meu html:

```
<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    </body>

</html>
```

Porém quando inicio a aplicação a seguinte mensagem aparece :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ifFilterProvider <- ifFilter
```

Alguém já passou por problema semelhante?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a documentação, você deve injetar o $routeProvider desta maneira:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
       .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
   });
}])
```

Neste link você pode acompanhar passo a passo de como fazer: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Resolvido.Muito obrigado Marco Antônio!